# can arangoDB aql skip filters by condition?

Tags: javascript, arangodb, aql

i work for a bbs app recently, and when i use the aql, i got a problem, for example:

```
//params:.com/t/123?&digest=true
=>
  FOR t IN threads
    FILTER t.digest == true && some conditions
    RETURN t
```

and the result is as expected,but when the parameter 'digest' is undefined or false, i want it returns all the threads..not which 'digest' = false, so i have to use if...else to write two almost same code, just remove the condition 't.digest == true' for example:

```
if(params.digest) {
  return `digest == true && conditions`
} 
return `conditions`
```

i'm using javascript, please give me a direction...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`HAS(document, attributeName)`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Functions/Document.html#has) to check whether the attribute is present in the document.

```
FOR t IN threads
  FILTER (!HAS(t,"digest") || i.digest == true) && conditions
  RETURN t
```

Comment: params is generated by url, if visitor wants to view digest threads=>**params.digest=true**, and i will add the condition **t.digest==true** into the query,but if visitor view as normal, i have to add a similar codes, i mean i want to a convinient way like this:

Comment: params is generated by url, if visitor wants to view digest threads=>**params.digest=true**, and i will add the condition **t.digest==true** into the query,but if visitor view as normal, i have to add a similar codes, i mean i want to a convinient way like this:`filter ${params.digest? 't.digest == true && ' : ''} conditions`

Comment: sorry about the comments ,i am a beginer of this site,  thank you for helping me